# How to insert and update data in Bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I haven't found the exact answer that how to insert and update data in bootstrap table.

The data is coming from a URL in JSON format.

I have to use multiple URLs in a same table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/bootstrap-table.css">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="margin : 100px;">
            <button class="btn-primary btn" onclick="load();" >Load Table</button>
            <button class="btn-primary btn" onclick="reload();">Update Table</button>
        </div>
        <table class="table" id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
                    <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
                    <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <script>
            $('#table').bootstrapTable({});
            function load(){
                var data = [{
                        id: 1,
                        name: 'Item 1',
                        price: '$1'
                    }, {
                        id: 2,
                        name: 'Item 2',
                        price: '$4'
                    }]; 
                $('#table').bootstrapTable("load", data);
            }
            function reload(){
                var data = [{
                        id: 3,
                        name: 'Item 3',
                        price: '$2'
                    }, {
                        id: 4,
                        name: 'Item 4',
                        price: '$6'
                    }]; 
                    $('#table').bootstrapTable("load", data);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If the data is coming from an API as JSON, you need to first download the JSON from the API endpoint and store it in a javascript variable and load

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/get2abhi/91t224n2/)

Comment: hows this 'load' method different than $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: mydata
    });

Comment: @AnuragDaware its not, your code sample is a better solution

Comment: there are more other options can be used instead of "load"

Comment: does this also update editable table in the database records?

Answer (score 0):

Say the json data is held in a javascript array called myList at index 0 & you are inserting into myTable, use the 'insertRow' option for bootstrap table to insert as the last row at the end of the table, as below:

```
var rowId = $("#myTable >tbody >tr").length;
$(myTable).bootstrapTable('insertRow',{
            index: rowId,
            row: myList[0]
         });
```